# My program is not deallocating space correctly

Tags: c, malloc, tokenize

I have this code here that is tokenizing a string. This line check if a string have quotes and returns the string without quotes. If I get something from the user, for example `Hello "nice" day`, it will return `hello nice day`:

```
char* str = take_quotes(line, stderr);
```

The function `take_quotes` is allocating space so I need to deallocate space in my tokenize function.

I thought that after I use the line I could free the space before returning my tokens, but when I do that I lose whatever is in my tokens. How should I free the space that was returned from `take_quotes`?

```
char** tokenize(char* line){
    if(line == NULL)
        return NULL;

    char* str = take_quotes(line, stderr); //free space

    char **tokens = malloc( sizeof( char * ) );
    *tokens = NULL;
    size_t n = 1;

    const char *delim = " \t \n";

    char *p = strtok( str, delim );

    int success = p != NULL;

    while ( success )
    {
        char **tmp = realloc( tokens, ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );

        if ( tmp == NULL )
        {
            free( tokens );
            tokens = NULL;

            success = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tokens = tmp;

            tokens[n - 1] = p;
            tokens[n] = NULL;
            ++n;

            p = strtok( NULL, delim );

            success = p != NULL;
        }
    }

    free(str);
    str = NULL;

    return tokens;
}
```

When I change my line

```
tokens[n - 1] = p;
```

to

```
tokens[n - 1] = strdup(p);
```

I get many errros in Valgrind

```
==8175== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8175==    definitely lost: 12 bytes in 3 blocks
==8175==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8175==      possibly lost: 6 bytes in 1 blocks
==8175==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8175==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8175== 
==8175== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==8175== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: `tokens[n - 1] = p`: instead of assigning the pointer to a buffer that would be freed copy the string. You can do that using `strdup(3)` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtok` tokenizes the given string *in-place*, by inserting NUL terminating bytes into the string at the delimiters. No additional memory is allocated. When you free `str`, you are destroying the memory that contains these tokens.

One approach is to make copies of your tokens, allocating memory for each along the way.

[`strdup`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) can be used for this purpose:

```
tokens[n - 1] = strdup(p);
```

If `strdup` is not available on your system, then you will have to rewrite its functionality (hint: `strlen` + `malloc` + `strcpy`, and don't forget additional space for the NUL terminating byte!).

When it is time to free `tokens`, you will have to free each of the individual elements it contains first.

---

A contrived example of freeing each element of a *jagged array*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void free_tokens(char **tokens) {
    for (char **t = tokens; *t != NULL; t++)
        free(*t);

    free(tokens);
}

int main(void) {
    char **tokens = malloc(3 * sizeof *tokens);
    tokens[0] = strdup("hello");
    tokens[1] = strdup("world");
    tokens[2] = NULL;

    for (char **t = tokens; *t != NULL; t++)
        printf("token:[%s]\n", *t);

    free_tokens(tokens);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I just edit my question with what happen when I use strdup. I had tried using before but it's making my program with more errors. Maybe is because I did not undertand how to do the last part that you mention, "when freeing the tokens it needs to be individual". Can you explain further?

Comment: @p20xx I've updated the answer to include an example of freeing such a data structure.